# Postman UI is extremely slow on my Windows 10

Tags: postman

What can I do to make Postman more usable? I have to wait more than a second after every single click to get the UI to respond.

I tried the tip with setting the system environmental variable of POSTMAN_DISABLE_GPU=true, but didn't have much luck.

**UPDATE:**
RAM: 16GB,
Processor: i7-855U @ 1.8GHz (8 CPUs),
Hard drive: SSD

I know VSCode is an Electron app, but it runs fine. I don't have the Postman Chrome extension installed either.

Comment: Can you tell your specs, ram etc. Electron apps are very slow on PCs without SSD

Comment: I added the additional info

Comment: You could try https://insomnia.rest/ or https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RapidAPI.vscode-rapidapi-client RapidAPI Client VSCode Extension, which i use. VSCode has a lot of optimizations to make it faster. And postman is slow. Maybe because your processor is 1.8GHz

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue after I was forced to upgrade to online account (v10.18.10).

In my case what helped was to close all the tabs, I had many open, never closed them in months, seems like every time you modify a request a new tab is opened.